# Visual studio code autocomplete not working

Tags: python, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I've just downloaded the visual studio code python extension, and the autocomplete doesn't really work. When I press ctrl+space, instead of giving me smart options, it give me just my variable names. for example:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z37JE.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you wait for the extension to finish loading and did you set the file type to `Python` or save that buffer as a `.py` file?

Comment: Are you using some virtual environment configuration? (venv, pipenv...)